# PostgreSQL now() value don't change value in function

Tags: postgresql

I need measure timelaps for testing the duration of function...
1) at the begin of function I assign value of now() to a variable called v_start;
2) before end the function I assign value of now() to a variable called v_end;

the problem is: the value of now() don't change during execution of function

Example

```
...
begin
 v_start := now();   ex. "2018-02-14 10:03:52.394263+01"
 ...
 ...
 v_end := now();  -- this value is equal to v_start

 select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now()-now())/3600 into v_timelaps;

-- v_timelaps is always 0;

end;
```

Any solutions??? Thanx!

Comment: `now()` is a timestamp of transaction, not statement - use `clock_timestamp()` instead

Comment: I'm sorry.... the select is select extract(epoch from (v_end-v_start)/3600 into v_timelaps;

Comment: unfortunately I'm tried and the result don't change...

Comment: Today I'm out... Thanx, the problem is solved

Answer (score 4):

It is not supposed to. Because function runs in transaction and transaction start time does not change while function runs.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

> `clock_timestamp()`   `timestamp with time zone`  Current date and time
>   (changes during statement execution);

or

> `statement_timestamp()`   `timestamp with time zone`  Current date and
>   time (start of current statement);

not the

> `now()` `timestamp with time zone`    Current date and time (start of
>   current transaction);

formatting mine.

also check the https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: `statement_timestamp()` is another alternative - start of the current statement